# Grabbing the item in the last array element

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array of items and I want to grab the number item in the last array, I need the able to grab it in the last item, I feel like this is pretty simple but I tried using the end() function and it do not seem to work, here is the example array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [number] => 1
        [mode] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2018-03-20 15:23:58
        [question_text] => Hello
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [number] => 2
        [mode] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2018-03-20 15:23:58
        [question_text] => Hello 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [number] => 3
        [mode] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2018-03-20 15:23:58
        [question_text] => Hello 3
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [number] => 4
        [mode] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2018-03-20 15:23:58
        [question_text] => Hello 4
    )

 )
```

So im trying to only grab [number] from the last array item in the array

Answer (score 0):

`end()` is the right function but you also need to get the property value as its an array of objects not an array of arrays.

`echo end($array)->number;`

or

```
$item = end($array);
echo $item->number;
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume the array is stored in a variable called $array:

```
echo $array[sizeof($array) - 1)]->number;
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this will not work for associative arrays.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Misread the OP and thought it was an associative array inside an indexed array.

Comment: I see, but my comment is still valid. The answer works for this case but not if the first level is associative.